# Probability of Impending Earthquake

Tags: real-analysis, probability, geometry, recreational-mathematics, conditional-probability

Site-specific intensity of an impending earthquake at the location is strong (S), moderate (M),or weak (W). Moderate ground shaking is three times more likely than strong shaking; weak shaking is 3 times more likely than moderate shaking. The probability that the facility will fail depends on the intensity of the ground shaking. The failure probability is $0.3$, $0.05$ and $0.001$ for strong, moderate, and weak shaking, respectively.

1. What  is the  probability  of  failure  of  the  facility  during  the  impending earthquake?
2. If  the  facility  fails,  what  is  the  probability  that  the ground  shaking  was strong?

Greetings to the Forum People. I am new to Probabilistic concepts and I am stuck with this question; it would be great help if one could answer these question or provide an idea of how to move forward.

Comment: See [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Comment: @user2661923 thanks for replying. However I am quite confused about the first question. There I need to get the Total Probability right?. I cannot use Bayes theorem there. Could you please suggest how to Proceed further?

Comment: The problem is somewhat poorly worded.  The way that I guess the problem is to be interpreted is that there will definitely be ground shaking during the earthquake, and the chance of strong/moderate/weak ground shaking will be $p_1 = (1/13), p_2 = (3/13), p_3 = (9/13),$ respectively.  Then, let $f_1, f_2, f_3 = 0.3, 0.05, 0.001,$ respectively.  Then chance of failure is $(p_1f_1) + (p_2f_2) + (p_3f_3).$

Comment: You are right that part (1) does not use Bayes Theorem.  However Part (2), which uses the result from part (1) definitely does use Bayes Theorem.  Incidentally, the best way to develop skill at Probability/Combinatorics problems is to *force* your intuition to stretch.  Intuition is disproportionately important in Probability/Combinatorics, compared to other Math subjects.

Comment: @user2661923. Thanks for the brief Explanation. for the Second Part of the Question the Probability to find out  would be P(S/F) right?. which would be according to Bayes theorem  P(S/F)=(P(F/S)*P(S))/(P(F)). I know P(S) which is p1 as you have explained and I know  P(F), which is the Total Probability , we have got from the 1st Part. However I am stuck with the P(F/S). is it 0.3?. As you have suggested Intuition is the main thing in solving Probability , since I am relatively new I am taking my time to get a hang of it.

Comment: P(S/F)- Probability the ground shaking was string given the Facility Failed ,                       P(F/S)- Probability of facility being failed given the Ground shaking was strong

Comment: $$p(S|F) = \frac{p(S ~\text{and} ~F ~\text{both occur})}{p(F)}.$$  This is based on the idea that $p(S|F) \times p(F) = p(S ~\text{and} ~F ~\text{both occur}).$

Comment: @user2661923 thanks again. However for p(S and F both occur) I need to use Multiplication rule right?. or is P(S) and P(F) can be statistically independent and can I use Result of Statistical Independent rule?. A reply would be really helpful

Comment: Re-read the question.  You are given the chance of Strong shaking.  You are also given the chance of failure **if** strong shaking $~= p(F|S) = 0.3$.  So $p(S ~\text{and}~ F) = p(S) \times p(F|S).$

Comment: Yup got it right !!. Thanks a lot for your help @user2661923